# How to make only one widget focusable in a custom listview?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, focus

I have a custom listview with one checkbox and two textviews. I'm using a custom adapter to present the list view. The problem is that the onItemclick function doesn't work for the checkbox if I focus on the checkbox directly, it works only when the list is focused first and then checkbox.I want my listview to work similar to checkedtextview where the checkbox gains focus by default.Can anybody suggest me a workaround for this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to list view activity and change according to your specification.

```
View v;
LayoutInflater li =(LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
v = li.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        //Action  
    }
});
```

Comment: I have a custom listview in which the checkboxes are present I want the checkbooxes to get focus when clicked on an item in the listview.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a click listener to your `view` returned with the getView() method as follows:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
/// checkboxview.clearFocus()
/// checkboxview.requestFocus()
     }....
```

---

EDIT. onclicklistener for checkbox:

```
 CheckBox chckKill = new CheckBox(context);
            chckKill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View v) {
                //is chkIos checked?
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
        ///// your code here
        }    
      }
    });
```

Comment: My problem is that only checkbox should have focus in the list, the textviews shouldn't gain focus. My onclicklistener for listview works fine but the focus is gained by the textviews, the checkboxes only work after clicking on the textview.

Comment: setFocusable(false) on textviews and requestFocus() for your checkbox again.

Comment: That works but how can I set onclicklistener for my checkboxes?

Comment: should I replace the view.onclicklistener with the listener for checkbox?